# Need help calculating the amount of time spent traveling

Tags: java

I am having trouble calculating the time spent traveling. I attached some images one is what I'm trying to get and the other is what I am getting. I find it difficult to calculate the time because of the change of speed.
Is there any recommendations of how i should go about calculating the estimated time traveled.

```
public class YourCarProblem {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        int cont;
        int gas = 0;
        double miles=0;
        int mph=0;
        int counter = 1;
        int con = 0;
        int total=0;
        int totalmph=0;
        double time=0;
               
        System.out.print("Are you going on a trip(1=yes or 0=no)?: ");
        cont = input.nextInt();        
        
        if (cont==1) {
            System.out.print("How many gallons of gas in you tank(Integer 1-20):");
            gas = input.nextInt();
            gas+=gas;

            System.out.print("Enter leg distance(Miles)");
            miles=input.nextDouble();
            total+=miles;

            System.out.print("Enter leg 1 speed(MPH)");
            mph=input.nextInt();
            totalmph+=mph;
            
            System.out.print("Is there another leg to your trip(1=yes or 0=no)");
            con=input.nextInt();
            counter++;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Thank you have a good day"); 
        }
        
            
        while(con>0) {
            if (con==1) {
                System.out.printf("Enter leg %d distance(Miles): ",counter);
                miles=input.nextDouble();
                total+=miles;
             
             
                System.out.printf("Enter leg %d Speed(MPH): ",counter);
                mph=input.nextInt();
                counter++;
                System.out.print("Is there another leg to your trip(1=yes or 0=no)");
                con=input.nextInt();
             }
             else if(con==0) {
                 System.out.print("have a good day");
             }
          
        }
        time = total/mph;
      
        System.out.printf("You traveled about %d miles in about %f",total,time);
    }
}
```

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85Mu3.png)

[Actual output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDKgG.png)

Comment: Do you not need to store your average mph?

Comment: If the speed entered for each leg is an *average driving speed* for that leg, then all you need to do is calculate `time += miles / mph` inside the loop (and once in the beginning). That will come out as 41 minutes if the same values are used as in the expected output image, but it is not clear why the expected output is 41.4 minutes there, the .4 part seems off. If 41.4 is the correct answer, please describe how 41.4 was calculated with the numbers in that image.

Comment: Please do not post images of code/errors/data. Instead post the code/errors/data as text in a code block. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Apart from this, this doesn't seems like a programming problem, but instead a math problem.